# Textout with weird chars if using accents - Lazarus

Tags: winapi, lazarus, freepascal

I am converting a Marquee Component from Delphi to Lazarus.

I have a problem with textout.

If my chars has no accent all works well, but If I use accent chars I am get weird chars with  this piece of code

```
{ Output the Text to the memory bitmap }
FScrollText:='não bastão'; ->I set it in my code  only to test
TextOut(FMemoryBitmap.Canvas.Handle,FScrollScreenPos,0,PChar(FScrollPartString),Length(FScrollPartString));  --> Error I get weird chars on Screen
//Here I have strange chars on screen
```

Here is my complete procedure:

```
procedure TScrolling.DoScrolling(Restarting: Boolean);
var
  ARect : TRect;
  OutY  : Integer;
begin
  { Set colors }
  Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
  FMemoryBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;

  { When restarting, set default values }
  if Restarting then begin
    Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
    FScrollScreenPos   := ClientWidth;
    FScrollCurrentChar := 1;
    FScrollPartString  := '';
  end;

  try
    { Clear the bitmap }
    ARect := Rect(0,0,FMemoryBitmap.Width,FMemoryBitmap.Height);
    FMemoryBitmap.Canvas.FillRect(ARect);

    { Exit if there is no text to scroll }
    if Length(FScrollText) > 0 then begin
      { Decrease the current output position }
      Dec(FScrollScreenPos,FScrollAmount);

      { Remove text from the beginning until the scrolling position is around 0 }
      if (FScrollScreenPos < 0) then begin
        if Length(FScrollPartString) > 0 then while (FScrollScreenPos+TextWidth(FScrollPartString[1]) < 0) do begin
          Inc(FScrollScreenPos,TextWidth(FScrollPartString[1]));
          Delete(FScrollPartString,1,1);
        end;
      end;

      { Fill up text at the end until PartString is wider than the client rectangle }
      while FScrollScreenPos+TextWidth(FScrollPartString) < ClientWidth do begin
        FScrollPartString := FScrollPartString+FScrollText[FScrollCurrentChar];
        Inc(FScrollCurrentChar);
        if FScrollCurrentChar > Length(FScrollText) then FScrollCurrentChar := 1;
      end;

      { Output the Text to the memory bitmap }
      FScrollText:='não bastão';  --> Only to test
      TextOut(FMemoryBitmap.Canvas.Handle,FScrollScreenPos,0,PChar(FScrollPartString),Length(FScrollPartString));  --> Error I get weird chars on Screen

      { Now draw the memory bitmap }
      OutY := 0;
      if FAutoCenter then OutY := (ClientHeight-FMemoryBitmap.Height) div 2;
      BitBlt(Canvas.Handle,0,OutY,ClientWidth,FMemoryBitmap.Height,FMemoryBitmap.Canvas.Handle,0,0,SRCCOPY);
    end;
  except
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Are you calling TextOutA or TextOutW. What is PChar? PAnsiChar or PWideChar? What encoding is your text?

Comment: Hi, I am calling TextOut. In source code of lazarus, I can see: PChar               = ^Char.   I am using native encoding with the line posted above. See:  FScrollText:='não bastão';

Comment: You didn't answer a single one of my questions. You need to dig deeper. Try to answer each question. If you don't understand the questions, ask. An image might help us deduce the answers.

Comment: OK, I will try again.

Comment: You ask me: 1.Are you calling TextOutA or TextOutW?Answer: TextOutA  2.  What is PChar? PAnsiChar or PWideChar? Answer:I dont know but lazarus defines PChar=^Char 3. What encoding is your text? Answer: I am new in Lazarus, I just assigned a string var to accented chars as FScrollText:='não bastão' and used Textout(calling TextOutA)

Comment: How can I know the encoding used for Lazarus, when I assign a string var to an accented text? I suppose is Unicode (UTF-8 for Lazarus) because the documentation says: The RTL and the FCL of FPC <= 2.6 expect ANSI strings. But I am using FPC 3.0

Comment: I believe a compiler option can switch between UTF-8 and UTF-6. Is Char AnsiChar or WideChar. TextOutA doesn't support Unicode. You'll want TextOutW and UTF-16 text. If you don't understand any of this it will pay to do some learning.

Comment: Don't just call it "weird", document *exactly* what you see.  Do keep in mind that it might be your text editor doing this, saving the source code file in an encoding you did not expect.

Comment: I solved with the next. I did var FWScrollText:widestring ; FWScrollText:= UTF8ToUTF16('não bastão');
      TextOutW(FMemoryBitmap.Canvas.Handle,FScrollScreenPos,0,PWideChar(FWScrollText),Length(FWScrollText));  Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Use `FMemoryBitmap.Canvas`'s method instead of API calls: `TextOut` -> `FMemoryBitmap.Canvas.TextOut` and `BitBlt` -> `FMemoryBitmap.Canvas.Draw`.

Comment: That looks reasonable, but @Abelisto may well be right that it would be better to get the high level framework to do the heavy lifting

Comment: Thank you Mr David for your patience and advices.